# I broke Minecraft via teleportation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft and I wanted to find an ice spike biome, so I just teleported 10000 blocks away, and I repeated to try to find it.

Unfortunately, I got frustrated beacuase I couldn't find it, and so I just teleported 3000000 blocks, came back and it said, "Connection Lost, Invalid Position".

It then exited me to the server list. I don't know why so I'm just asking why. I was in a Singleplayer world and it exited to the Server List!

FYI how do I delete a question beacuase to many people down voted this so now I can't answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it took you to the server list, but if you somehow get outside the world limit (30 million+ blocks from 0,0), the "Invalid position" thing happens.

Somewhat easy fix for this: get an NBT editor like [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac)- you can change your player's coordinates from there, then when you re-enter the world you'll be in the correct place. NBTExplorer is relatively intuitive.

Comment: @SixSided Has this worked for you, then?

Comment: Yes it has and I found my spike biome

Comment: @SixSided You're welcome, enjoy your spike biome. :^)